# Smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\sqrt[5]{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I was thinking that the minimal subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\sqrt[5]{2}$ would include all elements of the form $\{x + y\sqrt[5]{2} \}$ where $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$. However, why is it required to include additional powers of $\sqrt[5]{2}$ in the minimal subfield? In other words, I believe the right answer would be that there would be elements of the form $\{a + b\sqrt[5]{2} + c(\sqrt[5]{2})^2 + d(\sqrt[5]{2})^3 + e(\sqrt[5]{2})^4 + f(\sqrt[5]{2})^5 + g(\sqrt[5]{2})^6\}$ where $a,b,c,d,e,f,g$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$. Why is this the case, though?

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need the 5th and 6th powers.

Comment: Why do you believe that is the right answer?

Comment: Can you find rational numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $(\sqrt[5]{2})^2=x+y\sqrt[5]{2}$?

Comment: Oh, those were actually typos in which I didn't mean to type the 5th and 6th roots! Sorry about that! But I see all of your points, thank you :) So in general, is it the case that if you want to find the minimal subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\sqrt[n]{m}$, we would require $n-1$ powers (assuming $m$ is prime)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to approach this problem by providing an explicit construction of the field. The smallest field containing an algebraic (over $\mathbb{Q}$) number $\alpha$ will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle$, where $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

The minimal polynomial of an element $\alpha$ is an *irreducible* polynomial which has $\alpha$ as a root. The irreducibility allows you to say this field is the smallest such field.

The isomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle$ to the form embedded in $\mathbb{C}$ is just the morphism which sends $x \mapsto \alpha$.

So find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[5]{2}$, then construct the quotient field and apply the isomorphism. You should arrive at precisely the representation you have without the 5th and 6th powers.

Comment: And if the polynomial $P(x) = x^5-2 $ of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ (that we can write as $P(x) = \prod_{m=0}^4 (x-\sqrt[5]{2} e^{2 i \pi m /5})$ when seen in $\mathbb{C}[x]$) is reducible then $P(x) =  R(x)S(x)$ with $R \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ and $deg(R) = 1$ or $2$. 

 If $deg(R)  =1$ then $R(x) = x-\sqrt[5]{2} e^{-2 i \pi m /5}$ i.e. it is not in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, and $deg(R)= 2$ means $R(x) = (x-\sqrt[5]{2} e^{2 i \pi m /5})(x-\sqrt[5]{2} e^{-2 i \pi m /5}) = x^2 +ax +\sqrt[5]{2}^2$, still not in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

 Hence $P$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: I'm sure that is correct. But, Eisenstein's criterion provides a neater proof.

Answer (score 1):

Because the field contains $\sqrt[5]2$, and is a ring, it also needs to contain $\sqrt[5]2^2$ by closure of multiplication. But $\sqrt[5]2^2$ is not possible to write as $x+y\sqrt[5]2$ with $x, y$ rational, so the set $\{x + y\sqrt[5]2\}$ is not a ring. The same goes for $\sqrt[5]2^3$ and $\sqrt[5]2^4$.